# How to Call a Formatting More than Once in Java?

Tags: java, file, methods, formatter

To make it simple, I have a class called FileEditor:
        package modmaker;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class FileEditor {
public static Formatter projectFile;
public static String modName;

public void overWriteFile(){
    try {
        projectFile = new Formatter(modName+".txt");
        System.out.println("Wrote project file");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing project file");
    }
}
public void addBlock(){
    projectFile.format("blocks "+Blocks.blockName+" "+Blocks.blockDisplayName+" "+Blocks.doesEmitLight+" "+Blocks.lightValue+" "+Blocks.doesGenNaturally+" "+Blocks.genBelowLevel+" "+Blocks.genRariety+" "+Blocks.genClump+" "+Blocks.blockTexturePath);
    projectFile.close();
}
}
```

When the user first enters the program, the overWriteFile method is called, making the file.  Then the user proceeds to another window, where the define the block.* variables and then when a actionPerformed on a button is called, I want addBlock() to be called, formatting the file with the current variables, but when I try to do this multiple times, I gives me console errors... help please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to the file each time `addBlock()` is called, then remove the line `projectFile.close()` there (or probably even better, change it to `projectFile.flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the formatter until you're done with it.